# How to version control a Flex/Flash Builder application's release build files using Subclipse?

Tags: apache-flex, svn, flash-builder, subclipse

I need to store the release build of my Flash Builder (Flex) application in Subversion.  When I try to add it to version control via Subclipse I get a warning telling me that I have asked to version control one or more resources that otherwise would have been ignored.  Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can get around it?  I've gotten around this one time in the past by adding the build release's directory to the repository using another Subversion client, i.e. outside of Eclipse/Flash Builder, but when I rebuilt the release later I was unable to get Subclipse to see the changes between the base/head revisions and the new local versions of the build release files.

I realize that what I'm doing is non-standard and I suspect that there are default svn:ignore settings someplace which are causing this to happen, but I can't figure out where these are in order to modify/bypass them.  Or maybe there's something else going on?

Thanks in advance for any insight and/or help with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Eclipse-specific feature.  Eclipse has a feature where files that are produced by compilers or generates inside Eclipse can be marked in Eclipse as "derived" resources.  Eclipse team providers are supposed to ignore these files automatically.  AFAIK, that is the only reason the feature exists.

So Subclipse still allows you to manually choose one of these files to version, but it warns you that you selected files that Eclipse said to ignore.

It is possible (but I have no idea) that Flex Builder has some setting to control whether or not it marks these files as derived.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark.  Is it possible that I can build my release using Eclipse/Flash Builder, and then close Eclipse/Flash Builder and use another Subversion client to check in the "derived" files?  I've been hesitant to do this since doing so may corrupt the Subversion accounting/config files if the non-Subclipse Subversion client is using a different version of svn libraries etc. than Subclipse.  What can I do to make sure that the non-Subclipse client will be compatible with Subclipse, i.e. how can I make sure that I can use them interchangeably and not shoot myself in the foot?

Comment: This should be very doable and clients like TortoiseSVN or the command line can coexist fine with Subclipse.  You just need to align the Subversion version of the client.  If you are using Subclipse for SVN 1.6.x or 1.7.x get an equivalent SVN Client for that version.  You will also need to Refresh your project in Eclipse after so that it sees the changes made outside Eclipse.